# Received Data Zeroed Out After Encountering First Byte Equal to Zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, nvidia-jetson-nano

1. Summarize the Problem:

I wrote a userspace SPI driver in linux for the NRF24L01+ transceiver. My goal is to send files to a server. A jetson nano is the sender, and a raspberry pi 3b+ the receiver. Both the spi and nano are running Linux.

I can consistently send packets and receive acknowledgements.

However, the issue is whenever I send a packet such as `0x ff ee dd 00 cc bb aa` the receiver only receives the packet `0x ff ee dd 00 00 00 00`. So what is happening is that whenever the first byte encountered is zero, the rest of the packet becomes zero. This causes the files I send to become corrupted.

I was able to reproduce this bug with a char array having a similar pattern. I noticed this trend when I printed out the file contents I was sending on the transmitter and receiver.

2. What I've tried:

I've tried altering my SPI read function. What I thought was happening was the chip select line was being flipped high early. This did not work, I got the same results.

I've printed the packets before calling the `ioctl()` function from the transmitter and the packet remains intact.

I've printed the return value of the `ioctl()` function to see how many bytes I was receiving and sending. I was sending 31 bytes from the transmitter, and receiving 32 bytes from the receiver. So it doesn't look like my reads and sends are failing.

If I had a logic analyzer my next step would be to check the SPI pins on the transmitter, but unfortunately I don't have one.

I've added a 10uF decoupling capacitor on the transceivers and that sped up communication.

3. Show Some Code:

Receiver side:

```
/**
 *      Reads the payload when data pipe
 *      is available.
 *
 *      spi_dev_fd: file descriptor for spi device.
 * */
int nrf_rx_read(int spi_dev_fd, char * payload, int * pipe, int * bytes)
{
        int pipe_temp, rtn;

        // TODO: Add timeout.
        do
        {
                rtn = nrf_rx_pipe_available(spi_dev_fd, &pipe_temp);

        }while(rtn != 0);

        if(rtn == 0)
        {
                char status;

                if(bytes != NULL)
                {
                        char size;
                        spi_read_msg(spi_dev_fd, R_RX_PL_WID, &status, &size, 1);
                        *bytes = (int) size;
                }


                spi_read_msg(spi_dev_fd, R_RX_PAYLOAD , &status, payload, (int) NUM_PAYLOAD_BYTES);

                *pipe = pipe_temp;

                char msg;
                msg = RX_DR;
                spi_send_msg(spi_dev_fd, W_REGISTER | STATUS, &msg, 1);

                return 0;
        }

        return 1;
}

bool nrf_rx_pipe_available(int spi_dev_fd, int * pipe)
{

        char addr = NOP;
        char status;
        spi_read_msg(spi_dev_fd, addr, &status, NULL, 0);

        if((status & RX_DR) > 0)
        {
                *pipe = (status >> RX_P_NO) & 0x07;

                if(*pipe > 5)
                {
                        return 1;
                }

                return 0;
        }

        return 1;
}

int spi_read_msg(int spi_dev_fd, char addr, char * status, char * copy_to, int len)
{
        char data_buffer;
        char recv_buffer[len + 1];
        struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer;

        memset(&xfer, 0, sizeof(xfer));
        memset(&recv_buffer, 0, sizeof(recv_buffer));

        data_buffer = addr;
        xfer.tx_buf = (unsigned long) &data_buffer;
        xfer.rx_buf = (unsigned long) recv_buffer;
        xfer.len = len + 2;
        xfer.bits_per_word = 8;
        xfer.speed_hz = 1000000;
        xfer.cs_change = 0;
        xfer.rx_nbits = len * 8;
        xfer.tx_nbits = 8;

        int res = ioctl(spi_dev_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), xfer);

        if(res > 0)
        {
                status[0] = recv_buffer[0];
                if(copy_to != NULL)
                {
                        string temp = string(recv_buffer);
                        temp = temp.substr(1);
                        strncpy(copy_to, temp.c_str(), len);
                }

                // debug code
                for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                {
                        printf("copy_to: %x \n ", copy_to[i]);
                }
                // end debug code.
        }

        return res;

}
```

Transmitter side:

```
/**
 *      Function to load a payload and send a packet.
 *
 *
 *      spi_dev_fd: file descriptor for spi device.
 * */
int nrf_tx_send_packet(int spi_dev_fd, char * payload, int len)
{
        int rtn;
        // Put low so we can add the payload.
        gpio_set_value((unsigned int) GPIO_CE, (unsigned int) GPIO_LVL_LOW);
        // Set a new payload.
        nrf_tx_new_payload(spi_dev_fd, payload, len);

        // Start tx transmission.
        gpio_set_value((unsigned int) GPIO_CE, (unsigned int) GPIO_LVL_HIGH);


        do
        {
                rtn = nrf_tx_pending_send(spi_dev_fd);

                if(rtn == 2)
                {
                        char clr = MAX_RT;
                        spi_send_msg(spi_dev_fd, W_REGISTER | STATUS, &clr, 1);
                }
        }while(rtn != 1);

        // Go back to standby mode
        gpio_set_value((unsigned int) GPIO_CE, (unsigned int) GPIO_LVL_LOW);    // Setting chip enable to 0.

        char reg = W_REGISTER | STATUS;
        char val = RX_DR | TX_DS | MAX_RT;
        spi_send_msg(spi_dev_fd, reg, &val, 1);

        return 0;
}

int spi_send_msg(int spi_dev_fd, char addr, char * data, int len)
{
        char data_buffer[len + 1];
        char recv_buffer;
        struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer;

        memset(&xfer, 0, sizeof(xfer));
        memset(&recv_buffer, 0, sizeof(recv_buffer));

        data_buffer[0] = addr;
        for(int i = 1; i < len + 1; ++i)
        {
                data_buffer[i] = data[i-1];

                printf("databuffer[i]: %x \n", data_buffer[i]);
        }
        xfer.tx_buf = (unsigned long) data_buffer;
        xfer.rx_buf = (unsigned long) NULL;
        xfer.len = len + 1;
        xfer.bits_per_word = 8;
        xfer.speed_hz = 1000000;
        xfer.cs_change = 0;
        //xfer.rx_nbits = 8;
        xfer.rx_nbits = 0;
        xfer.tx_nbits = (8 * len) + 8;

        int res = ioctl(spi_dev_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), xfer);

        printf("res: %i \n", res);

        return res;

}
```

I tried to add all the relevant code, sorry if it is a bit much. Main thing to look at is the send and receive functions. They all work as expected until I encounter the zeroed out byte.

If I am missing any information that can help someone out please let me know and I can add it. I think the send and receive functions are the most important however. I'm able to set and read the registers of the transceiver.

Comment: The data is being trimmed because I am converting the received data to a string and bytes with 0x00 are being interpreted as null terminated, will post fix for this soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can send files now!

The fix was done in `spi_read_msg()` function.

The problem was I was converting the buffer received to a string, which caused the data to be trimmed when the byte `0x00` was encountered. This is also equivalent to the null terminating character.

Receiver code:

```
int spi_read_msg(int spi_dev_fd, char addr, char * status, char * copy_to, int len)
{
        char data_buffer;
        char recv_buffer[len + 1];
        struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer;

        memset(&xfer, 0, sizeof(xfer));
        memset(&recv_buffer, 0, sizeof(recv_buffer));

        data_buffer = addr;
        xfer.tx_buf = (unsigned long) &data_buffer;
        xfer.rx_buf = (unsigned long) recv_buffer;
        xfer.len = len + 2;
        xfer.bits_per_word = 8;
        xfer.speed_hz = 1000000;
        xfer.cs_change = 0;
        xfer.rx_nbits = len * 8;
        xfer.tx_nbits = 8;

        int res = ioctl(spi_dev_fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), xfer);

        if(res > 0)
        {
                status[0] = recv_buffer[0];
                if(copy_to != NULL)
                {
                        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                        {
                                copy_to[i] = recv_buffer[i + 1];
                        }
                }

        }

        return res;

}
```